# Form control attribute label error message from WC3

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm getting a WC3 error that has me completely confused.

The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control. …you are human:  Write code in box »

```
<label for="txtCaptcha"> Write code in box &raquo; <span id="txtCaptchaDiv" style="color:#29372F; font-weight:bold;"></span><!-- this is where the script will place the generated code --> 
<input type="hidden" id="txtCaptcha" name="txtCaptcha"/></label><!-- this is where the script will place a copy of the code for validation: this is a hidden field -->
<input type="text" name="txtInput" id="txtInput" size="30" />
```

I have for="txtCaptcha" referring to the hidden input control id, so I am not sure what WC3 is saying. Any help will be appreciated.

Additional information was requested. I attempted to put the entire form here, but for some reason the code block does not accept all the code. It breaks it up and then when I try to submit, it won't let me because the code is not in a code block.

The page is here http://skeeterz71.com/gothic/quote-page.html line 641
Line 641, Column 55: The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control. …you are human:  Write code in box »

Thank you

Comment: Why a hidden input should have a label? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The error you mention is as follows:

[image]

The problem is that the hidden field is not labelable, as you can read directly from the specifications:

[**4.10.2 Categories**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html)

> Some elements, not all of them form-associated, are categorized as
>   labelable elements. These are elements that can be associated with a
>   label element.
>
> button input (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state) keygen
>   meter output progress select textarea

[**HTML/Elements/input/hidden**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/hidden)

```
<input type="hidden">
```

> The hidden state represents a value that is not intended to be
>   examined or manipulated by the user.